# Sinch : Operator not Supported Error

Tags: sinch, sms-verification

I am using Sinch framework for Mobile verification. For some numbers Sinch returns me an error that says **"Operator not supported"**.

I am unable to understand why this error is returned. Could some one point me to the documentation where this is explained.

If of any help I'm number concerned is an Indian number.

Thank in advance.

Updated - December 04, 2015

Heres the code that returns me the error

```
#import <SinchVerification/SinchVerification.h>

@interface EnterPhoneNumberViewController () {
 id<SINVerification> _verification;
}
@end

@implementation EnterPhoneNumberViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

 _verification = [SINVerification SMSVerificationWithApplicationKey:@"blah-blah-blah-blah" phoneNumber:phoneNumberTextField.text];
            //set up a initiate the process
 [_verification initiateWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

            if(!success) {
                //code returned with failure
                NSLog(@"Error while verification : %ld %@",(long)[error code],[error localizedDescription]);
                [errorLabel setText:[error localizedDescription]];
            }
            else {
                //code returned with Success
                NSLog(@"SMS With Code Successfully Sent");
            }
        }]; 
}
```

Comment: @Sumurai8 Thanks for the prompt reply. I have updated the question with the code in question. Hope this will suffice. Thanks again

Comment: did you see my reply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

today we released a new sdk to help you neter number, check out downloads sinch.com/download this shoule help you getting correct numbers sent for verification. The error means that that number/carrier is not supported. This can be for a number of reasons, google voice number, blocked because of fraud an unsupported carrier.

If you think that that is an error on that particular number please contact support@sinch.com with that number and we can look in to it.